# Change 'standard error' to 'standard output'

Tags: powershell, stdout, stderr

I have a PowerShell script that writes to the error output. The script can be as simple as the following:

```
Write-Error 'foo'
Start-Sleep -s 5
Write-Error 'bar'
```

The script I actually call spawns an external process that takes a while to process and writes to standard error.

Now when I call the script like this:

```
. myScript.ps1
```

I get the error message with PowerShell's usual behaviour (i.e. red text and lots of debugging information). As that text has no relation to PowerShell in my actual application, I don't need those debugging information and it only makes the result less readable (and impossible to process).

Is there a way to redirect that output directly into standard output, so that I just get the text?

I tried something like this:

```
Write-Host ( . myScript.ps1 2>&1 )
```

But that delays the output until everything is completed.

About the “debugging information”, when I run the script right now, the output looks like this (in red):

```
C:\path\to\myScript.ps1 : foo
Bei Zeile:1 Zeichen:2
+ . <<<<  'C:\path\to\myScript.ps1'
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Write-Error], WriteErrorException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.WriteErrorException,myScript.ps1

C:\path\to\myScript.ps1 : bar
Bei Zeile:1 Zeichen:2
+ . <<<<  'C:\path\to\myScript.ps1'
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Write-Error], WriteErrorException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.WriteErrorException,myScript.ps1
```

When I run the script with `Write-Host ( . myScript.ps1 2>&1 )`, where the error output is written to the standard output, I get a result like this:

```
foo bar
```

That is exactly what I would like the output to be, except that the `Write-Host (..)` makes the output only appear after the script has terminated, so I cannot receive any information on the progress of said script.

To come actually closer to my actual problem (because it’s hard to explain that with pure PowerShell); I’ve got the following Python script that resembles approximately what the command line program I use does, i.e. it does some processing and prints out the progress to the standard error:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import sys, time
sys.stderr.write( 'Progressing... ' )
sys.stderr.flush()
time.sleep( 5 )
sys.stderr.write( 'done.\n' )
sys.stderr.flush()
```

Now, when I call it with `python script.py`, it works correctly and prints out the “progressing” line, waits 5 seconds and then prints the “done” to PowerShell (as normal text). The problem is now that I want to run this *in a job*, like this: `Start-Job { python script.py }`.

The job gets started correctly, and also works fine in the background, but when I want to check its progress via `Receive-Job <id>`, I get no output at all at first, and after the script/program finished (i.e. after the 5 seconds), I get the following output (in red again):

```
Progressing... done.
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (Progressing... done.:String) [], RemoteException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError
```

Obviously that is not what I am trying to get. Instead I want to get the actual output that was printed to the standard error, both *live* (i.e. when it happens in the script) and without that PowerShell related debugging text.

Comment: Sorry but I don't understand your question. Have you any control on the code of the script? Why are you using `write-error`? What debugging information are you speaking about?

Comment: I am using a command line program which I have no control about. That program returns all its information via the standard error output. But when you access the standard error output in PowerShell, PowerShell adds debugging information to it, which is really annoying (compare `Write-Error test` and `Write-Host test`). I basically want the output that is written to the error output appear in the standard output, so I can work correctly with it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the *edit* section of the question, this should be suitable:

```
. MyScript.ps1 2>&1 | %{ Write-Host $_ }
```

It writes just "foo" and "bar" and they appear as soon as they happen.

**EDIT**

Actually this is even simpler and works fine, too:

```
. MyScript.ps1 2>&1 | Write-Host
```

But I keep the original answer. That code allows to process the output (`$_`) dynamically and do something else (i.e. not just write it to the host).

**EDIT 2**

External program that writes to STDERR:

```
using System;
namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 100; ++i)
            {
                Console.Error.WriteLine("Step " + i);
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The script that starts this application as a job and receives its output periodically.

```
$ErrorActionPreference = 'continue'

$job = Start-Job { C:\TEMP\Test\ConsoleApplication1.exe 2>&1 }
for(;;) {
    Receive-Job $job | Write-Host
    Start-Sleep 2
}
```

The script does exactly what you need (for your *edit 2* section): it shows the output as soon as it is available and it does not show unwanted extra error information.

P.S. This version works, too:

```
$job = Start-Job { C:\TEMP\Test\ConsoleApplication1.exe }
for(;;) {
    Receive-Job $job 2>&1 | Write-Host
    Start-Sleep 2
}
```

Comment: While this redirects the standard error to output correctly, this too delays the actual output until the script finished. Please see my *edit 2* section in the question for further information of what I actually want.

Comment: You keep changing the question :). Looking forward for the *edit 3* section.

Comment: I was looking forward to it too, but it seems it is no longer necessary, because your solution works just fine! Thank you very much! :)

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
$erroractionpreference = "silentlycontinue"
.\myscript.ps1
```

Comment: This removes the output completely though. I need to access what the program/script writes to the error output, as it is the only way to get actual information from it.